# Using Hiddenfield Value in jQuery option

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Using Chart.js, I have put a bar graph down which takes a few options to configure. One of those is 'data'. For example, this will give me 3 bars at those values.

```
data: [10, 13, 15]
```

What I would like to now try do is use the value of a HiddenField to replace that data option, so that I can produce the bar values dynamically from code behind.

HiddenField

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HFData" runat="server" Value="10, 13, 15" />
```

jQuery. First to assign the value of the hidden field, and then trying to use this.

```
var x1 = document.getElementById('<% =HFData.ClientID %>').value;

data: x1
```

I have also tried;

```
data: [x1]
```

The problem I am having is that it is treating x1 as one long string and not taking into account he comma separated values as if i was typing this in as per the first example where it works.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did some more investigation and found that I needed to create an Array first, and this then allowed me to use my HiddenField values which were comma separated, within my jQuery script.

HiddenField

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HFData" runat="server" Value="10, 13, 15" />
```

jQuery

```
var xData = document.getElementById('<% =HFData.ClientID %>').value;

    var ArrayData = [];
    ArrayData = xData.split(',');
```

This allowed me to use it against the data property of a graph

```
 data: ArrayData
```